# Does Chrome support OID Filters in the TLS handshake

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ssl, certificate, authentication

Cite from [rfc8446](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.2.5)

> The "oid_filters" extension allows servers to provide a set of
> OID/value pairs which it would like the client's certificate to
> match.  This extension, if provided by the server, MUST only be sent
> in the CertificateRequest message.

This would be useful for client certificates with different EKU (document signing vs. identification).

Comment: Do you mean being able to use a "document signing" certificate without it having the "TLS Client" EKU?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes, that would be a signing certificate in my case. I just don't want that certificate in the Chrome's certificate list prompt when user is first accessing the website.

Comment: Then the question is why *does* it appear in the first place if it doesn't have the TLS EKU...

Comment: If it doesn't have a TLS EKU it's Client Certificate by default.

Comment: Normally it would need the "TLS Client" EKU to be a Client Certificate. If it had *no* EKUs, it would also be a client certificate, but if it has some EKUs but none of them are the "TLS Client" EKU then I'm surprised Chrome offers it at all.

Comment: It doesn't have any EKUs, field is missing from the signing one.

Answer (score 0):

OID Filters have to do with the TLS handshake and are not dependent
to Chrome. They are server-side constraints upon the certificates
that the server may accept.

A clear definition is given in the article
[A Readable Specification of TLS 1.3](https://davidwong.fr/tls13/#section-4.2.5):

> **filters**: A list of certificate extension OIDs [RFC 5280] with their allowed value(s) and represented in DER-encoded [X690] format.
> Some certificate extension OIDs allow multiple values (e.g., Extended
> Key Usage). If the server has included a non-empty filters list, the
> client certificate included in the response MUST contain all of the
> specified extension OIDs that the client recognizes. For each
> extension OID recognized by the client, all of the specified values
> MUST be present in the client certificate (but the certificate MAY
> have other values as well). However, the client MUST ignore and skip
> any unrecognized certificate extension OIDs. If the client ignored
> some of the required certificate extension OIDs and supplied a
> certificate that does not satisfy the request, the server MAY at its
> discretion either continue the connection without client
> authentication or abort the handshake with an
> "unsupported_certificate" alert.

In the unlikely event that the client has multiple certificates
for one server, where some obey OID filters and some may not,
the client is supposed to select the most-matching certificate
to do the handshake.

Comment: What I meant is will Chrome prompt users with the filtered list of certificates when establishing connection? This is more of a UX question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I deleted this ill-thought sentence.

Comment: @Desperado: I never got the Chrome certificate selection dialog so don't know how it's generated. It's pretty rare to have more than one certificate per one website.